# How to clear user data associated with an app

Tags: ios

On the simulator, Reset Content and Settings... will clear all apps and data.

I would like to clear out all the data used by the app I'm developing without wiping the entire phone.  Note that uninstalling the app (by wiggling and pressing the x button) does not seem to wipe the data as when I reinstall the app, some settings are still persisted.

Comment: Preserved on the simulator or a device?

Comment: I want to delete the app data on a device

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places outside of the app's sandbox directory where settings are saved: User defaults and the keychain. User defaults get completely erased when the app is deleted. If the app you are using saves to the keychain, you should delete all the key/value pairs you might have saved. That should do it.

Comment: Minor point - the `NSUserDefaults` file is actually in the app sandbox, not outside. It's in `<app root>/Library/Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% on this but for the iPhone simulator how about just going to the following folder location

> /Users/**{insert_your_username}**/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/**{simulator_version}**/Applications/

and then delete the appropriate folder here (just browse one level deeper into those 32-character-long folders to identify which application settings it holds)